# How run Jenkins job on a specific number of nodes defined in parameter

Tags: jenkins

I need to run a Jenkins job on a different number of nodes each time.

Tried to play with Node Label + Job Restrictions plugins, but they can't help.
The last allows to limit a number of concurrent runs, but eventually Jenkins will run job on all nodes, defined in Label.

The goal is simple:
I'd like to add a parameter, for example "NodesNumber".
And depending on it to run job on a specific number of Nodes in pool (2,3, etc..).

Did anybody solve such problem?

Answer (score 0):

if your job is a free style you can use only one node at a time.
if it is a pipeline job you can split each process(module/functionality) and put it in separate stage/ node(using label) execute them in parallel , so that your job will execute in multiple nodes at a same time based in your groovy script.

```
parallel firstBranch: {
    node1(label)
     {
       //function execution
     }
}, secondBranch: {
    node2(label)
     {
       //function execution
     }
},
failFast: true|false
}
```

Comment: The first statement is not correct. With NodeLabel plugin we can run a build on all nodes matching a label at a time. So the question is how to limit the number in a "label" pool.

Comment: may be you could limit the number of executors of a slave node with particular label

Comment: @Vladimir - the NodeLabel plugin didn't work for me. Do you have any link to some documentation which helps me to use the plugin better? I'm using GitHub pull request builder to build my jobs though. I'm not sure if that is the problem